# Automated testing shell scripts

Tags: shell, testing

I am looking for a tool to test automatically a set of shell scripts such as Windows (DOS) and UNIX.

The idea is to be able to inject into the script a few keystrokes and to be able to analyze the displayed feedback.
Of course, my goal is to automate the execution of such tests.

Someone has an idea of such a reference tool?

Best regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not finally found what I expected, so I wrote it.
If you are interested, here is the solution I implemented: http://code.google.com/p/batchtester.

For now, it's in French (sorry).
You are free to use it, to fork it, to get inspired ... in short it is free.

Best regards, Chris